# ASP.net kerberos dropping down to NTLM sporadically

Tags: asp.net, kerberos, delegation

Background (just the relevant pieces):
We have a large intranet asp.net 2.0/3.5 app.
Web servers are Windows Server 2003 on an AD domain.
Clients are on Windows, IE 6-8.
Windows Authentication, with a custom principal created from the Windows Identity.
Web servers sit behind an F5 NLB which forwards the user to a specific web server.  (The reason for this is a limitation w/ our company's F5 dealing w/ kerberos).
There are no system wide problems like dropping sessions, or timeouts, or overloaded servers, everything's running fine in general.

One piece of functionality requires delegation - we are connecting to a network file share as the authenticated user, using the Kerberos token given to us by the domain/web server.

SPNs, ACLs, etc, seem to be set up properly.

99.x percent of the time, it all works.  The problem we're seeing is every now and again, on a refresh, the token drops from kerberos down to ntlm.    I can see the login on the web server's event log showing one call getting this:

Logon Process: Kerberos
  Authentication Package: Kerberos

And a subsequent call (usually after 10 or 20 page loads) getting this:

Logon Process: NtLmSsp 
  Authentication Package: NTLM

Anyone have any insight as to what might be making a subsequent postback sometimes go NTLM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All the tools and techniques you need to identify the issue are in [Troubleshooting Kerberos Errors](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7DFEB015-6043-47DB-8238-DC7AF89C93F1&displaylang=en). That document never failed me.

> NTLM Fallback
>   You might find that the
>   security log recorded an event in
>   which logon occurred using NTLM when
>   it should have occurred using Kerberos
>   authentication.
>
> **Problem**
>   There are two
>   situations in which this might happen:
>    - The first situation is where the
>   system attempts authentication using
>   the Kerberos protocol but it fails. As
>   a result, the system attempts to
>   authenticate using NTLM. Windows
>   Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows
>   2000 use an algorithm called Negotiate
>   (SPNEGO) to negotiate which
>   authentication protocol is used.
>   Although the Kerberos protocol is the
>   default, if the default fails,
>   Negotiate will try NTLM.
>    - The second
>   situation is one in which a call to
>   Negotiate returns NTLM as the only
>   protocol available.
>
> **Confirmation**
>   The
>   first situation will result in a
>   failed Kerberos authentication that
>   you can investigate by examining
>   errors in the event log or data
>   packets captured by Network Monitor.
>   Both investigation methods are
>   discussed later in this document...

Comment: Nice, haven't seen that before.  Thanks!